# How to disable unselect row in NSOutlineView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I have `NSOutlineView` and I don't know how to disable unselect row in it. It's problem when I click into `NSOutlineView` where isn't any cell, selected row is unselected. Is there any way, how to keep selected row when someone click into `NSOutlineView`? But It has to work normally when someone click onto other cell. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Interface Builder go to the **Attribute inspector**, under the **Table View** section make sure `Empty` is not checked.